# PJSIP connection errors on ios 11 when coming from background during Push Notification

Tags: ios11, pjsip, ios12

How do we recover a lost PJSIP UDP socket when coming from background during a CallKit Push notification?  We get the following errors when trying to register with Asterisk server.

```
ioq_select  Error replacing socket [120009]: Bad file descriptor
```

We've tried closing and recreating the pjsip transport when we encounter these errors, but that is effective only ~50% of the time.  By the time the transport is successfully created the call is lost.  Is there a more robust way to handle the UDP socket loss?

Any attempt to proactively close down the socket/transport when entering the background (in application:applicationDidEnterBackground) results in an unregister packet being sent to asterisks server.  Any background calls go straight to voicemail.

We are testing on ios 11 and 12 using pjsip 2.8